# While running same spring batch job in multi tenant environment started failing,

Tags: spring-batch

My system supports multi-tenancy until now every tenant had its own job repository (i.e. under a tenant-specific schema). Meaning “myJob” could be executed for tenant X and tenant Y and be shared without any risk. But while running  “myJob” execute for tenant X and tenant Y it starts failing. We have our reader and writer in @stepscope and steps with @jobscope.  Below is an error log captured from the DB.

[2020-07-21 08:08:12:710] [DEBUG] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-372] [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl] container_id=W2026553  Message: On TransactionImpl creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:710] [DEBUG] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-372] [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl] container_id=W2026553  Message: begin
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:715] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-1] [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] container_id=W2026553  Message: Processing flush-time cascades
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:715] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-1] [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] container_id=W2026553  Message: Dirty checking collections
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:715] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-1] [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] container_id=W2026553  Message: Flushed: 0 insertions, 1 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:715] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-1] [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] container_id=W2026553  Message: Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:715] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-1] [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter] container_id=W2026553  Message: Listing entities:
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:715] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-1] [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter] container_id=W2026553  Message: com.cerner.revcycle.parallelprocessor.entity.BatchJobStaging{creDTime=2020-07-21T08:08:09+05:30, itemId=12886, jobId=14, lastCngDTime=2020-07-21T02:38:12.715Z, objectIdentifier=541, status=SUCCESS}
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:715] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-1] [org.hibernate.SQL] container_id=W2026553  Message: update BatchJobStg set CreDTime=?, ItemId=?, JobId=?, LastCngDTime=?, Sts=? where ObjId=?
Hibernate: update BatchJobStg set CreDTime=?, ItemId=?, JobId=?, LastCngDTime=?, Sts=? where ObjId=?
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:715] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-1] [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl] container_id=W2026553  Message: On TransactionImpl creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:715] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-1] [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl] container_id=W2026553  Message: begin
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:715] [INFO] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-1] [com.cerner.rccloud.data.sharedtenants.SharedTenantData] container_id=W2026553  Message: SharedTenantData:: DomainTenantId= RCC-SYSTEM; SharedTenantId=null; incoming tenantId=RCC-SYSTEM
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:715] [INFO] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-1] [com.cerner.rccloud.data.RccHikariDataSource] container_id=W2026553  Message: RccDataSource::getConnection() request for tenant=RCC-SYSTEM; Schema=rcc-parallel-processor_RCC-SYSTEM
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:716] [DEBUG] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-372] [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl] container_id=W2026553  Message: rolling back
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:720] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-1] [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl] container_id=W2026553  Message: committing
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:721] [ERROR] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-372] [org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob] container_id=W2026553  Message: Encountered fatal error executing job\n+ Throwable: org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0\n\n    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.nullableSingleResult(DataAccessUtils.java:97)\n\n    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:784)\n\n at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:809)\n\n at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.synchronizeStatus(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:308)\n\n    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update(SimpleJobRepository.java:166)\n\n   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor346.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\n    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\n    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\n at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)\n\n   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)\n\n    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\n\n    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)\n\n  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)\n\n    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\n    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)\n\n at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy131.update(Unknown Source)\n\n   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor346.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\n    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\n    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\n at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)\n\n   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)\n\n    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\n\n    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)\n\n    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\n    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)\n\n at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy131.update(Unknown Source)\n\n   at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.updateStatus(AbstractJob.java:440)\n\n    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:314)\n\n at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:147)\n\n    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n\n
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:725] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-2] [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl] container_id=W2026553  Message: On TransactionImpl creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:725] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-2] [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl] container_id=W2026553  Message: begin
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:725] [INFO] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-2] [com.cerner.rccloud.data.sharedtenants.SharedTenantData] container_id=W2026553  Message: SharedTenantData:: DomainTenantId= RCC-SYSTEM; SharedTenantId=null; incoming tenantId=RCC-SYSTEM
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:725] [INFO] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-2] [com.cerner.rccloud.data.RccHikariDataSource] container_id=W2026553  Message: RccDataSource::getConnection() request for tenant=RCC-SYSTEM; Schema=rcc-parallel-processor_RCC-SYSTEM
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:728] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-3] [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] container_id=W2026553  Message: Processing flush-time cascades
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:728] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-3] [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] container_id=W2026553  Message: Dirty checking collections
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:728] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-3] [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] container_id=W2026553  Message: Flushed: 0 insertions, 1 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:728] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-3] [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] container_id=W2026553  Message: Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:728] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-3] [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter] container_id=W2026553  Message: Listing entities:
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:728] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-3] [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter] container_id=W2026553  Message: com.cerner.revcycle.parallelprocessor.entity.BatchJobStaging{creDTime=2020-07-21T08:08:11+05:30, itemId=12968, jobId=16, lastCngDTime=2020-07-21T02:38:12.728Z, objectIdentifier=623, status=SUCCESS}
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:728] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-3] [org.hibernate.SQL] container_id=W2026553  Message: update BatchJobStg set CreDTime=?, ItemId=?, JobId=?, LastCngDTime=?, Sts=? where ObjId=?
Hibernate: update BatchJobStg set CreDTime=?, ItemId=?, JobId=?, LastCngDTime=?, Sts=? where ObjId=?
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:731] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-1] [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] container_id=W2026553  Message: Processing flush-time cascades
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:731] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-1] [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] container_id=W2026553  Message: Dirty checking collections
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:731] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-1] [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] container_id=W2026553  Message: Flushed: 0 insertions, 1 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:731] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-1] [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] container_id=W2026553  Message: Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:731] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-1] [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter] container_id=W2026553  Message: Listing entities:
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:731] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-1] [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter] container_id=W2026553  Message: com.cerner.revcycle.parallelprocessor.entity.BatchJobStaging{creDTime=2020-07-21T08:08:10+05:30, itemId=12926, jobId=15, lastCngDTime=2020-07-21T02:38:12.731Z, objectIdentifier=581, status=SUCCESS}
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:731] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-1] [org.hibernate.SQL] container_id=W2026553  Message: update BatchJobStg set CreDTime=?, ItemId=?, JobId=?, LastCngDTime=?, Sts=? where ObjId=?
Hibernate: update BatchJobStg set CreDTime=?, ItemId=?, JobId=?, LastCngDTime=?, Sts=? where ObjId=?
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:732] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-3] [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl] container_id=W2026553  Message: committing
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:733] [DEBUG] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-372] [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl] container_id=W2026553  Message: On TransactionImpl creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:733] [DEBUG] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-372] [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl] container_id=W2026553  Message: begin
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:734] [DEBUG] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-372] [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl] container_id=W2026553  Message: rolling back
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:735] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-1] [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl] container_id=W2026553  Message: committing
Exception in thread "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-372" org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:736] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-4] [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl] container_id=W2026553  Message: On TransactionImpl creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:736] [DEBUG] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-4] [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl] container_id=W2026553  Message: begin
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:736] [INFO] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-4] [com.abc.rccloud.data.sharedtenants.SharedTenantData] container_id=W2026553  Message: SharedTenantData:: DomainTenantId= RCC-SYSTEM; SharedTenantId=null; incoming tenantId=RCC-SYSTEM
[2020-07-21 08:08:12:736] [INFO] [scopedTarget.parallelProcessingTaskExecutor-4] [com.abc.rccloud.data.RccHikariDataSource] container_id=W2026553  Message: RccDataSource::getConnection() request for tenant=RCC-SYSTEM; Schema=rcc-parallel-processor_RCC-SYSTEM
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.nullableSingleResult(DataAccessUtils.java:97)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:784)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:809)
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.synchronizeStatus(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:308)
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update(SimpleJobRepository.java:166)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor346.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy131.update(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor346.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy131.update(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:375)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:147)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, the root cause is not visible in what you shared.

Comment: Updated with full stack trace

Comment: The error `Throwable: org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0` is happening at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/193f82005a373819e5921c7e2255607cf239d14e/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/dao/JdbcJobExecutionDao.java#L307 which means no results are returned from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/193f82005a373819e5921c7e2255607cf239d14e/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/dao/JdbcJobExecutionDao.java#L91.

Comment: This means a thread is concurrently asking for a job execution that does not exist. Please provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example